# Memory error while making a new dataframe using columns of another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to make a new Dataframe using columns of another Dataframe. The code is as follows.

```
df1=df[['Time','Calling Minutes']]
```

However after this line the error is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Official Works\Data Health Check\Scripts\3G\3G Final KPI with P.py", line 11, in <module>
    df1=df[['Time','Calling Minutes']]
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2133, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2178, in _getitem_array
    return self._take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2143, in _take
    self._consolidate_inplace()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3677, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._protect_consolidate(f)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3666, in _protect_consolidate
    result = f()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3675, in f
    self._data = self._data.consolidate()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3826, in consolidate
    bm._consolidate_inplace()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3831, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4853, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4873, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = _vstack([b.values for b in blocks], dtype)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4919, in _vstack
    return np.vstack(to_stack)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 234, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
MemoryError
```

Need suggestion to overcome this error. I am using Python 3.5 (32 bit)

head is as follows:

```
               Time  CELLNAME   CellId NODEBNAME      RNC Integrity  \
0  2018-03-18 00:00        WF  61153.0        1W    RNC02      100%   
1  2018-03-18 00:00        WE  61419.0        1W    RNC02      100%   
2  2018-03-18 00:00        WF  14336.0        2W    RNC02      100%   
3  2018-03-18 00:00        WC  61336.0        1W    RNC02      100%   
4  2018-03-18 00:00        WA  50901.0        ZW    RNC02      100%   

   VS.HSDPA.MeanChThroughput.TotalBytes(byte)  HSDPA Service Drop Num  \
0                                3.338195e+08                     3.0   
1                                7.403250e+08                     4.0   
2                                5.970779e+08                     2.0   
3                                2.105562e+09                    11.0   
4                                6.859688e+08                     1.0   

   VS.HSUPA.MeanChThroughput.TotalBytes(byte)  HSDPA Service Drop Ratio(%)  \
0                                  41114435.0                        460.0   
1                                  45385524.0                        896.0   
2                                  53130310.0                       1238.0   
3                                 137530085.0                       2912.0   
4                                  43769059.0                       1040.0   

        ...         RRC.AttConnEstab.TmConvCall  RRC.AttConnEstab.EmgCall  \
0       ...                                 1.0                       0.0   
1       ...                                 0.0                       0.0   
2       ...                                 0.0                       0.0   
3       ...                                 0.0                       0.0   
4       ...                                 3.0                       0.0   

   VS.RAB.SuccEstabCS.Conv  VS.RAB.AttEstabCS.Conv  CS RAB Congestion Num  \
0                      7.0                     7.0                    0.0   
1                      1.0                     1.0                    0.0   
2                      6.0                     6.0                    0.0   
3                     12.0                    12.0                    0.0   
4                     18.0                    18.0                    0.0   

   3GGP CS RAB Att Estab  3GGP RRC Conn Att  VS.HHO.SuccInterFreqOut  \
0                    7.0               30.0                      0.0   
1                    1.0               33.0                      7.0   
2                    6.0               42.0                      3.0   
3                   12.0              106.0                      0.0   
4                   18.0               69.0                      5.0   

   VS.HHO.AttInterFreqOut  Calling Minutes  
0                     0.0            4.500  
1                     8.0            0.999  
2                     5.0           48.999  
3                     0.0            3.999  
4                     5.0          113.001  

[5 rows x 44 columns]
```

Comment: can you give us the .head() of the other table?

Comment: I have added the head inside the problem statement

Comment: Hmm, is MemoryError the final bit of debug message you get? Try using this instead df1 = df.loc[:, ['Time', 'Calling Minutes']].

Comment: Same error is occurring if I use df.loc

Comment: Are you able to access the series without trying to assign it to a new frame? just s1 = df['Calling Minutes'], s2 = df['Time']. Need to pinpoint what is throwing the error here.